# Running Eclipse with PyDev as root

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

i need to debug a program i wrote in Eclipse with PyDev plugin. However I can not debug it because Eclipse obviously does not have the permission to do so.
I always get the following error when debugging reaches the `send()` function.

> socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Running Eclipse with gksudo does not work either. It opens, but it says the editor could not be found.

> Could not open the editor: No editor descriptor for id
>   org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor

How do I fix this?

I can't post the full code, it's too long. Here is a kind of breakdown, which causes the same error. Eclipse is not allowed the execute the `send()` function. Executing it with sudo in the command shell works.

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP

class SomeIP(Packet):
    name = "SomeIP Packet"
    fields_desc=[XShortField("X", 0x1000),
                 XShortField("Y", 0x1000)]

SIP = SomeIP()

packet = IP(src="129.168.101.164",dst="192.168.101.143")/UDP(sport=1000, dport=1000)/SIP

send(packet, verbose=False)
```

Here is the error I get - the first line can be ignored.

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scapy_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    send(packet, verbose=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
    __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 307, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Are you sure this is about permissions? I doubt you need to run IDE as root to debug anything. Maybe the port is busy? Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145463/

Comment: Yes, I am. To run the program in the command shell I need to execute it as sudo, too. I tried to apply the solution in the answer, but I don't use a `serversocket`. How do I apply this solution then?

Comment: Your code might be very helpful here!

Comment: I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

Could you use another port number? If I understand your code correctly you try to open a port on number 1000. Since port numbers up to 1024 can only be used by root, setting the port number to something higher than 1024 could maybe solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately using higher port numbers does not work, either.